# Android: скриншот SurfaceView во время видеозаписи - чёрный экран

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder

Есть `SurfaceView`:

```
this.surf = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surf);
this.surf.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
this.surf.addCallback(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Cam.this.h = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Cam.this.h = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

});
```

и есть `MediaRecorder`, записывающий видео:

```
MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mMediaRecorder.setCamera(Cam.this.mCamera);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.MIC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(VideoSource.CAMERA);
mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(Cam.this.surf);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Cam.this.mParcelFileDescriptor[1].getFileDescriptor());
mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000);
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
mMediaRecorder.start();
```

Никаких проблем с записью видео нет. Но, почему-то, при получении скриншота приложения можно заметить, что вместо `SurfaceView` отображается чёрный прямоугольник. Вот код получения скриншота:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout); // основная компоновка (в моём случае RelativeLayout)
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
v.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
FileOutputStream o = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "frame.jpeg"));
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, o);
o.flush();
o.close();
```

и XML-код данной Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="test.Cam" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Как исправить ошибку, сделать так, чтобы `SurfaceView` не отображался чёрным прямоугольником на скриншоте?

---

Знаю один неплохой вариант, требующий root права:

> su /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.jpf

Сразу вариант не подходит, так как **root прав нет.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26303163/1263771

Comment: вторая мысль - зачем вам вообще скриншот? может вам на самом деле нужны снепшоты в процессе записи, по какому-нибудь событию от пользователя? для этого штатный способ есть.

Comment: @tse, какой способ? Да, мне нужен снимок камеры во время видеозаписи. Если это возможно, расскажите как. В интернете говорят так нельзя. `MediaRecorder` блокирует объект камеры на всё время использования и `mCamera.takeScreenshot(..)` выбросит исключение.

Comment: Гм, похоже, я ошибся, в смысле мои воспоминания уже устарели. Я делал такое, но сейчас ничего похожего на то, как я делал, не гуглится.  Но нашел вот такой ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36321147/1263771

Comment: @tse, там `Camera2` API, а это Android 5 и выше. Нужен минимальный не выше 4, то есть не выше API 16.